# Why do I get a 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier" error in this code?

Tags: sql, oracle, dml

I am trying to create 3 tables, and insert data into them by having employees with below 25% of average salary in EMPLOYEE_BOTTOM_25, employees above 10% of salary range in EMPLOYEE_TOP_10, and all other employees in EMPLOYEE_OTHERS.

I used a conditional insert for this, and used a select statement, but it says I keep having an error in the "Salary" right before the select statement (In "** **", Bolded.) How should I resolve this?

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_BOTTOM_25 (
    Employee_id    VARCHAR2(10),
    Employee_name VARCHAR2(35),
    Job_title VARCHAR2(35),
    Salary NUMBER (9,2)
);

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_TOP_10 (
    Employee_id    VARCHAR2(10),
    Employee_name VARCHAR2(35),
    Job_title VARCHAR2(35),
    Salary NUMBER (9,2)
);

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_OTHERS (
    Employee_id    VARCHAR2(10),
    Employee_name VARCHAR2(35),
    Job_title VARCHAR2(35),
    "Salary" NUMBER (9,2)
);


INSERT ALL
    WHEN Salary <= salarywage * 0.25 THEN
        INTO EMPLOYEE_BOTTOM_25
            VALUES(Employee_id,Employee_name,Job_title,Salary)
    WHEN Salary >= salarywage * 0.9 THEN
        INTO EMPLOYEE_TOP_10
            VALUES(Employee_id,Employee_name,Job_title,Salary)
    WHEN Salary <= salarywage * 0.25 AND Salary >= Salary * 0.9 THEN
        INTO EMPLOYEE_OTHERS
            VALUES(Employee_id, Employee_name, Job_title, **Salary**)
Select employeeid, firstname || ', ' || lastname as name, jobtitle, avg(salarywage) as salaraywage
From Employee
group by employeeid, firstname || ', ' || lastname, jobtitle;
```

Comment: Select one DBMS. Either MySQl or Oracle, not both. These are two separate and different DBMSs. Edit, remove wrong tag.

Comment: The entire premise of your query (which can't work btw) is flawed because as you add employees, their salary status may change. For example, if every employee record added was larger than the last, ALL employees would be in the EMPLOYEE_TOP_10 category, which is clearly incorrect.

Comment: A better approach would be to calculate this dynamically via a view, because as new employees are added and/or salaries are changed, the salary bracket will change for multiple employees.

Comment: If you thoroughly check each table and compare `salary` column between working tables and not, you'll find that in Oracle `salary != "Salary"`. Never use [quoted identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-3C59E44A-5140-4BCA-B9E1-3039C8050C49) as they are case sensitive